# how to transform any R object to the python set object using reticulate package

Tags: r, reticulate

I am able to transform from R's vector, list, matrix to python's corresponding object using reticulate.

However, is there any way to transform any R object to pythons's set object?

Comment: In which context do you like to do it? Are you importing R-wrapers within python or maybe using ipython/jupyter.....

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes I am using reticulate in R in Rstudio.

Answer (score 1):

According to an issue in reticulate github:

```
library(reticulate)
pybuiltins <- import_builtins()
pybuiltins$set(list(1,2,3))
```